# lstrip unexpected output: removes additional character

Tags: python

lstrip removed additional character, please help me understand it why. Is it removing all the input characters from the beginning?

```
'http://twitter.com/c_renwick'.lstrip('http://twitter.com/')
>>>'_renwick'
```

Comment: Because `'c' in 'http://twitter.com/'`. Read the docs for `.lstrip` - `help(str.lstrip)`. It would probably be easier to implement this with `.rsplit` instead.

Comment: you want `str.replace`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Or `os.path.basename()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands in that case, yes, that'd work. But what if the relative URL is deeper?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How do you mean?

Comment: I mean: `http://twitter.com/c_renwick/something` how does `basename` manage with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lstrip` takes a list of characters to remove from the string. As `c` is in the list you provided, it gets removed

To achieve what you actually want, use replace:

```
'http://twitter.com/c_renwick'.replace('http://twitter.com/','')
```